# Google App Engine request timing out on count() function

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I am using count() function to calculate the number of results returned by the query. The problem is that count is taking too long , that the request times out. Is there any way that i can make the count to respond quickly or any alternative to count() ?

```
query = MyModel.query().filter(MyModel.name.IN(['john', 'sara', 'alex']))
search_count = query.count()
```

if i remove the count line and just return the results it takes just couple of seconds.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately count doesn't scale.  You can only count 1000 items without using a cursor.  Secondly if you want to count do a keys only query (pulls less data from the datastore).

Really to keep a count relatively up to date for a large number of entities, you will need to use a task and run it every so often, (or trigger a task to be scheduled each time data is added/modified if it is infrequent) and store that value away some where.

Or think about why you really need a count ;-)  and how accurate it is.

Comment: "Or think about why you really need a count ;-) and how accurate it is": Good point!

Answer (score 0):

1. If you need count(), you should use the `keys_only` option as Tim Hoffman already suggested. That should save you enough time for counting small query results.
2. Be aware that count() actually runs through the complete query until the very last match in the index. This means, if your query matches millions of items in a huge index, you will see terrible request times and time-outs even with the `keys_only` option.

From a usability perspective it isn't likely that a user wants accurate numbers in large scales. Typically users will not even browse through dozens or even hundreds of pages.

### Counter with threshold accuracy

Consider using a counter that only is accurate up to a low limit, e.g. "41 items found", and beyond that limit use a generic display, e.g. "1000 or more items found". This is how text searches in GMail shows number of matches.

### Pre-calculated counter

Enter a generic term like "spaghetti" into Google search and you will see some incredibly high number, e.g. "5.3 million documents found". Then try to get to page number 1,000 or to match number 1,000,000. It won't work. And the number is inaccurate as well. For calculating number of matches ahead of time, you could write tasks / cron jobs (maybe with map-reduce) that will calculate the counters asynchronously. However, even in business use-cases the counter of an individual search query like in your example doesn't need to be accurate with large numbers because it is very probable that the counter is changing significantly while the user goes through the results.

### Shard counters

If you however need an accurate counter, for example the number of all sales orders in the datastore, rather than individual queries, you could write a counter and increase/decrease it with every new sales order that is created or deleted in the datastore. Depending on how you model the entity groups such counter might hit current datastore limitations in large volume writes (~ 1 write op per second per entity group, in reality maybe 3 to 4). See the article [Sharding counters](https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/sharding_counters) which explains how to build a scalable counter.

### Use Search API

You could use the full text search service in Google App Engine. Define an index (e.g. "Customer") with fields you want to search. Whenever a customer entity in datastore is updated, put an updated copy of it as document into the search index. In my experience, the Search API is scaling much better for complex searches in large indices. It also shows you a counter and provides your users with full text search capabilities.